# Credibility of dated data structure programming book

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I recently rented a book from my local library for c++, the books title is: "Data Structure Programming with the standard template library in c++" by Joseph Bergin. The problem is when i checked the publication date it read 1998, which is a pretty huge time frame given the speed of computer advances today. Will this book hurt me or help me? Here is an excerpt from an algorithm in my book:

```
//  THIS IS AN ALGORITHM EXPLAINED AS SELECTION SORT
template <class T>
void selectionSort(T* start, T* end)                //first off, i notice an excessive use of pointers, when usually 
{   for(T* where = start ; where < end ; where++)   // im told to work around pointers if i dont need to use them
    {   T* loc = where;                             //weird bracket formatting(old practice i would guess?)
        T small = *loc;
        for                                         //very strange method of organizing for loops used in the book
        (   T* inner = where + 1;
            inner < end;
            inner++;
        )
            if(*inner < *loc)
            {   loc = inner;
                small = *loc;
            }
        *loc = *where;
        *where = small;
    }
}
```

this code uses strange methods in order to make a selection sort. Pointers could easily be replaced with normal values, yet the book loves the use of pointers and odly formatted for loops. How far off is this code from a modern C++11 approach to a selection sort with arrays?

*They also declare all of their variables with a _ prefix, does this do anything special to variables? examples of declared vars:

```
int _Num1;
float _Select;
```

Comment: A new C++ standard was issued last year, so the standard library (the successor to the old STL) now includes hashtables. Your computer's speed probably doesn't matter when it comes to basic data structures; linear search is still too slow :)

Comment: I think that the book is ok to learn the basics and get a better understanding of the various concepts. You can then either get a more up to date book (perhaps boost instead?) or use the internet or your compilers manual pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I promise you every one that is known as a good programmer today read books from those date( or even before that ), so I don't think that it hurt you, since it is about concepts and concepts never change dramatically, but if you can find a newer book it will be awesome!

Comment: I'm actually re-reading a book(s) originally published in 1968.  Can you guess what it is?

Comment: @JohnDibling, is it "Roman Laughter: The Comedy of Plautus" ?

Comment: @Robᵩ:  Nope.  :)  Hint:  it's a computer book.

Answer (score 2):

You should get a new book, but that doesn't mean your current book is necessarily harmful.

The C++ language is defined by a Standard, which is written by an international committee.  Compilers implement this Standard to varying degrees, but they all follow the C++ Standard more or less.

Since 1998, there have been not one but two new Standards produced -- one in 2003 (often called C++03), and one just recently in 2011 (C++11).  The fundamental idioms that existed in 1998 are still relevant today, so learning those is still important.  But there have been substantial changes to the Standard Library, including the parts of the Standard Library that many people (mistakenly) refer to as the "STL".  There has been refinement to many of the idioms known in 1998 as our experience with the language grows, and there are new idioms possible in C++11 that weren't possible in 1998.

There is an excellent [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x) that enumerates many of the differences between C++11 and C++03, and there are even more differences in C++ from 1998.

Here is one new book that I have been reading. [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215)